# how can print value of two columns of a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on MVC3 asp.net. 
this is my sr=tatement in controller:-

```
ViewBag.rawMaterialRequired = (from x in db.RawMaterial 
 join y in db.ProductFormulation on x.ID equals y.RawMaterialID 
 where y.ProductID == p select new { x.Description, y.Quantity });
```

this is my code in View:-

```
 @foreach(var album in ViewBag.rawMaterialRequired)
         {
                @album<br />
         }
         </div>
```

this is my output:-

```
{ Description = Polymer 26500, Quantity = 10 }
{ Description = Polymer LD-M50, Quantity = 10 }
{ Description = Titanium R-104, Quantity = 20 }
```

this is my desired output:-

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by designing a view model:

```
public class ProductLineViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

then in your controller use this view model:

```
ViewBag.rawMaterialRequired = 
     from x in db.RawMaterial 
     join y in db.ProductFormulation on x.ID equals y.RawMaterialID 
     where y.ProductID == p 
     select new ProductLineViewModel 
     { 
         Description = x.Description, 
         Quantity = y.Quantity 
     };
```

and inside the view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(var product in (IEnumerable<ProductLineViewModel>)ViewBag.rawMaterialRequired)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.Description</td>
            <td>@product.Quantity</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That's was the first step into improving your code. The second step consists of getting rid of `ViewBag` and use strongly typed views and display templates:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = 
         from x in db.RawMaterial 
         join y in db.ProductFormulation on x.ID equals y.RawMaterialID 
         where y.ProductID == p 
         select new ProductLineViewModel 
         { 
             Description = x.Description, 
             Quantity = y.Quantity 
         };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view remove any ugly loops thanks to display templates:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductLineViewModel>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and inside the display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ProductLineViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model ProductLineViewModel
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Description)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Quantity)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you sooo much for this help, I really cant express my happyness about your help. God give you all happyness in your life... Really sir you have done very very valuable work for me. Thanks alot once again...